# If statement still going through when my condition should be false

Tags: c++, if-statement

I am attempting to write a Caesar encryption program. I have written two functions.

The first (sanitize) allows me to make sure that all strings are fully capitalized, here is the source code.

```
string sanitize(string message) {

    for(int i; i < message.length(); i++){
        message[i] = toupper(message[i]);
    }

    return message;
}
```

The second (caesar) encrypts the message given. Here is the source code for that as well.

```
string caesar(string c_message, char direction) {

    if (direction = 'R') {
        for(int j; j < c_message.length(); j++) {
            if((int)c_message[j] + 3 > 90) {
                c_message[j] = (char)(64 + (3 - (90 - (int)c_message[j])));
            } else {
                c_message[j] = (char)((int)c_message[j] + 3);
            }
        } 
    } else if (direction = 'L') {
        for(int i; i < c_message.length(); i++) {
            if((int)c_message[i] - 3 < 65) {
                c_message[i] = (char)(91 - (3 - ((int)c_message[i] - 65)));
            } else {
                c_message[i] = (char)((int)c_message[i] - 3);
            }            

        }
    } else {
        cout << "directions: 'L' or 'R'" << endl;
    }

  

    return c_message;
}
```

An example of execution :

```
int main(){
    cout << sanitize("HELLO") << " " << (char)3 << endl;
    cout << caesar("HELLO", 'L') << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The first if statement works, but the second does not.

Comment: direction = 'R' should be direction == 'R' same for L case, youre assigning R to direction not comparing. (and because the literal 'R' is not equal to 0 the condition is considered true)

Comment: The same for `if(direction = 'L' )` btw

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings. Such typos are very easy to detect for compiler, but hard to detect for hujmans.

Comment: also changing the signature to 'const char direction' would have caught it (since you'd be trying to modify a const variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    if (direction = 'R') {
    } else if (direction = 'L') {
```

These lines are wrong. `=` in C++ is *an assignment operator* and it sets the value of a variable in lefthand to the value of righthand. Then, it is evaluated to the new (righthand) value. Another point is that nonzero values are considered as true when used as condition.

You should use *a comparision operator* `==` instead of that like this:

```
    if (direction == 'R') {
    } else if (direction == 'L') {
```